# arrayList grow method JAVA overriding that function

Tags: java, arrays, list, overriding

please can someone explain to me how to override grow function? I mean the size is grow by old capacity - new capacity /2 +1(for exapmle, Array list collection). How to change that by overridin manually. I tried but couldnt do it. Thank for any help

Comment: java array list. I'm new here

Comment: Please don't subclass `ArrayList`. It's a concrete, very well-defined class and there's no sane reason to extend it. If your teacher told you to do that then stop listening to them. Subclassing should be used sparingly. See [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm studying java for month, just want to get how to do it by myself. I tried but couldnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList` is specifically designed not to let you do this.  You can't.

Comment: you mean i cant oveeride grow method formula of defining new array list when element == array.lenght?

Comment: That's correct.  You can't.